# How to display different bootstrap pages with a bootstrap navigation bar fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]How to display different html pages inside a html page (or without page reload) with a working bootstrap navigation bar fixed at the top all the time.I thought of putting all the contents in a single HTML page and just change the display property of containers(to hide or display containers)whenever I hear a navigation button being pressed.But this is quite messy as the whole website is almost in a single html file.I tried using JQuery's load function to load a html page inside a container.But it didn't work.

```
<nav id="navid" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Explore Music</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#trending_music">Trending Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about_us">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music Library</a></li>
        <li><button id="lscallbutton" type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginsignuppopup">Login/Signup</button></li>
        <li><button id="signoutbtn" type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-danger" style="display: none" onclick="signoutuser(1);">Sign-out</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In the above code,I need to change contents of current html page for displaying the music library retaining the navigation bar(this styling should be present in another html page which is loaded only when the "Music Library" is pressed dynamically optimizing the performance of the website hopefully).
Please correct me if I was wrong.

If my explanation seems unclear please visit www.gaana.com .This is the exact functionality I want.

What is an elegant design for this?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: im not really sure what u mean with an html page in an html page, are you looking for an <iframe>?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: @akshay what you are trying to do is **SPA** (**S**ingle **P**age **A**pplication) you just need to use a **Js framework** like **Vuejs**  or **Angular** or something else

Comment: @RamondeVries No not an iframe.See when I press Music Library (see inside list inside navbar) I need the content of the rest of current html page to change.How to do this.I have the styling of the Music Library in a separate HTML page.

Comment: @KrDjamel Oh.I am actually not understanding how to express what I want to do.For example,Please visit the following website  https://gaana.com/   In this website,after you press each navigation buttons,the content changes.

Comment: @RamondeVries please see my reply to KrDjamel.This is what I want to do exactly.

Comment: @akshay maby this can help u a bit?, https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/

Comment: @akshay this is the newer version of the other post: https://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/

Comment: @akshay are you trying to make a bootstrap template  or php application ?

Comment: @akshay check my answer if its working.

Comment: @Fiido93 sure iam not near my laptop now.I will execute and tell u after some time.Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Answer by using JavaScript**

You don't need to use PHP to change the content. You can use JavaScript. If you focus speed performance on your website use JavaScript.

JS

```
$(function(){

  $('#portfolio').click(function(){
    $('.home').addClass('hide');
    $('.portfolio').removeClass('hide');
  });

  $('#home').click(function(){
    $('.portfolio').addClass('hide');
    $('.home').removeClass('hide');
  });

})
```

Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nhojp2gq/)

Comment: No. I am not looking for the implementation you have shared. Your implementation just scrolls on the same page. But I want to change the contents such that current page details are dynamically changed. See www.gaana.com if u are not understanding what I want exactly.

Comment: Thanks.Can you help me with another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009267/firebase-storage-download-file-functionality-not-workingjavascript-web-applic

Comment: hi @akshay now i know what you mean. You no need use php to change the content. You can use using javascript. If you focus speed performance on your website you can use javascript. Please thumbs up if this help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I wanted to do. But one question since the whole functionality of multiple tabs is put in the same single webpage with different classes corresponding to different tabs,does it take longer to load the entire huge page. Is there any more efficient way.

Comment: I have upvoted Ur current answer.I couldn't mark it as solution bcoz I had already marked notsure answer as the solution.If u find a better solution kindly update it and comment to notify me.Thanks

Comment: No one uses this solution in real world websites or applications though. This is a nightmare SEO wise. Also is not really "speed performance" to have all pages in a single html file and show/hide them with js, it's the opposite.

Comment: Umm sorry, What do you know about SEO? What do you know the difference between server or client side rendering? How the difference between mine and yours effect SEO?

Answer (score 0):

A popular way to achieve this before react js, angular or vue became the norm (and still used btw) is through php.

You create different .php pages and load in their header through php a common header.php snippet.

So the feeling is that the header stays still and only the part below changes.

Example:

```
<div id="header">
<?PHP include_once('header.php');?>
</div>
<div id="main">
Main content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me however I had to change a lot of code.

Comment: Can you please help me with another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009267/firebase-storage-download-file-functionality-not-workingjavascript-web-applic